# About definition of metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

A metric space is an ordered pair (M,d) where M is a set and d is a metric on M $d:M \times M \rightarrow R$ such that for any $x,y,z \in M$. The following holds:

1. $d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y $
2. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
3. $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$

Question 1:  $d:M \times M \rightarrow R$ I know metric space is a function that it takes in M(where M is a set) and spits out a real number. But what does the $\times$ signify?

Question 2: how does the operation go? Since it is a distance between two points, so is it, say if x,y are two different points, then $d(x,y)=|x-y|=|y-x|=d(y,x)$, where $| \cdot|$ means absolute value sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The metric is a function for two variables. In general, such a function would be from a set $A\times B=\{ (a, b)\ |\ a\in A, b\in B\}$, and here $A=M=B$. That's just the cartesian product.

(2) It is not guaranteed that there is any operation. One may define the so called discrete metric by $d(x, y)=1$ if $x\neq y$ and $d(x, x)=0$ for all $x, y\in M$.

You have the sign wrong in the third condition, by the way. $d(x, z)\le d(x, y)+d(y, z)$. Draw a triangle to check this.